# Set colors on specific text inside Text() View

Tags: swiftui

So let's say that I have the following code:

```
Text("(Open)")
    .font(.caption2.weight(.bold))
```

I want to set `.foregroundColor(.green)` to just "Open" and not the parentheses inside view.

Is there a way to target just a specific piece inside a Text() view and apply modifiers to it?

Comment: This is not a valid question, please provide more informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the addition operator `+` with `Text` like you would on regular strings like so :

```
Text("(").font(.caption2.weight(.bold)) +
Text("Open").font(.caption2.weight(.bold)).foregroundColor(.green) +
Text(")").font(.caption2.weight(.bold))
```

Comment: This doesn't hurt anything performance wise does it? Also I did not know you can group them using an addition operator, thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know how it's implemented behind the scenes but considering it's the intended way to do it in SwiftUI and the operator was implemented specifically for this reason, I believe you should not worry about it. 
Here's the documentation by the way [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/+(_:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/+(_:_:))